# Filter comma-separated data-attribute against an array

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

I am building a filter for upcoming events and I have the general functionality ready, which worked perfect, as long as each event is of a single type (let's say: type "congress"). But now, there might be events of multiple types, with a value like "congress,hybrid".

So I need to check if ONE value in a comma separated data-attribut is part of a given array. e.g. the filter "congress" should find an entry with data-attribute="congress", but an entry with data-attribute="hybrid,congress" as well.

Thank you for any idea!

```js
$("#event_filter :checkbox").click(function() {
   doFilter();        
});


function doFilter() {
  $("#events li").hide();

  let eventtype = [];

  $("#event_filter :checkbox:checked").each(function() {
      eventtype.push($(this).val());
  });

  console.log("Eventtype: " + eventtype);

  $("#events li").filter(function() { 
      return $.inArray($(this).data("eventtype"), eventtype) != -1;
  }).show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="events">
   <li data-eventtype="Congress,Webinar">Event XY (Congress/Webinar)</li>
   <li data-eventtype="Hybrid,Congress">Event ABC (Hybrid/Congress)</li>
   <li data-eventtype="Congress">Event DE (Congress)</li>
   <li data-eventtype="Webinar">Event KLM (Webinar)</li>
</ul>
    
<div id="event_filter">
<input type="checkbox" value="Congress" id="cb_congress" /><label for="cb_congress">Congress</label> 
<input type="checkbox" value="Webinar" id="cb_webinar" /><label for="cb_webinar">Webinar</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="Hybrid" id="cb_hybrid" /><label for="cb_hybrid">Hybrid</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest map, toggle and some:

```js
const doFilter = () => { // map the values to an array
  const eventTypes = $("#event_filter :checkbox:checked").map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
  }).get(); // the .get() returns the JS array from the jQuery object

  $("#events li").each(function() {
    const events = $(this).data("eventtype").split(","); // split the events on comma
    const found = eventTypes.length === 0 || events.some(event => eventTypes.includes(event)); // toggle shows if true - either an empty array (nothing checked) or one of the events is in the array
    $(this).toggle(found);
  });
};

$("#event_filter :checkbox").on("click",doFilter);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="events">
  <li data-eventtype="Congress,Webinar">Event XY (Congress/Webinar)</li>
  <li data-eventtype="Hybrid,Congress">Event ABC (Hybrid/Congress)</li>
  <li data-eventtype="Congress">Event DE (Congress)</li>
  <li data-eventtype="Webinar">Event KLM (Webinar)</li>
</ul>

<div id="event_filter">
  <input type="checkbox" value="Congress" id="cb_congress" /><label for="cb_congress">Congress</label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Webinar" id="cb_webinar" /><label for="cb_webinar">Webinar</label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Hybrid" id="cb_hybrid" /><label for="cb_hybrid">Hybrid</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code works like a charm. But can you explain a bit what you're doing here? And: how do I add a second filter (let's say: event_location) to the given solution?

Comment: I updated. You now do feature creep. Post the relevant html and we can take a look. I think you can remove half of your code in the question since it is the same twice

Comment: You're right, I've updated my question

Comment: So where is the event location part

Comment: All fine @mplungjan, I was able to get it work with multiple options. Your code is much shorter than what I had before. Super helpful, thank you for taking the time!

Comment: One more question regaring mutliple filter values... I can find the items, that fit ALL of the filter values. But there is one occurance, where I need to find all items, that are either in list a OR in list b. Means, find all items that are true for filter 1 && 2 && 3 but also items that are true for filter 4 (although filter 1-3 my not be applicable for this item).

Comment: Just add: `eventTypes.length === 0 || events.some(event => eventTypes.includes(event) || locations.some(location=> locationsFromDataAttribute.includes(location)`

Comment: locationsFromDataAttribute is coming from... where?

Comment: I assume (from your other comment) that you wanted `<li data-eventtype="Congress,Webinar" data-eventlocation="Atlanta,New York">Event XY (Congress/Webinar)</li>` and `const locationsFromDataAttribute = $(this).data("eventlocation").split(",")`

Comment: ah, I see, just a given variable name.. ups :-D